# É possível utilizar o mesmo nome de uma coluna como nome de parâmetro num cursor?

Tags: sql, oracle, cursor

Possuo o seguinte cursor:

```
-- CÓDIGO OMITIDO
    DECLARE
      CURSOR CUR_AULAS(IDTURMA NUMBER) IS
      SELECT ID, IDCLIENTE
        FROM AULAS
      WHERE
        ATIVO = 1 
        AND IDTURMA = IDTURMA;
```

Sempre irá retornar verdadeiro pois ele acha que estou filtrando a própria coluna (IDTURMA) e não pelo parâmetro, se eu alterar o nome do parâmetro funciona corretamente mas é possível utilizar o mesmo nome tipo um `this`do Java?

Comment: pq nao utilizar `P_IDTURMA` no nome do parametro para melhor leitura do codigo?

Comment: Eu sei que posso utilizar, mas minha dúvida é se é possível ter o mesmo nome.

Comment: Não é uma boa prática o ideal é sempre identificar o objeto , usar um prefixo "P_" para parâmetros ajuda é muito a leitura do código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não é possível pois segundo a [documentação da Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/nameresolution.htm#LNPLS2038) para o PL/SQL, quando coluna e (parametros ou variaveis) tem o mesmo nome, a coluna tem precedência.

> If a SQL statement references a name that belongs to both a column and
>   either a local variable or formal parameter, then the column name
>   takes precedence.
>
> *Se um código SQL referencia um nome pertencente a uma coluna e a uma
>   variavel local ou parâmetro, então a coluna terá precedência.*

Comment: Então não é possível?

Comment: não, uma vez que ele vai tratar como campo da tabela e não como parametro

Comment: Boa, obrigado André! =)